# The character of portuguese can't print on php, what must i do?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i try to print this word,

```
echo "AUTO DETENÇÃO"
```

but the output is **AUTO DETENÃ‡ÃƒO** . This word is Portuguese.

Comment: Have you checked the output encoding?

Comment: i have read thats question ,,,[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through].
this is what i do,
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
but the result always like this  AUTO DETENÃ‡ÃƒO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your script file is saved as utf-8 but the data is sent to the client as if it was iso-8859 (or similar) encoded.
try

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

in your script before any output is sent to the client.
Then PHP will send an http response header that informs the client about the utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your encoding is set to a proper option for your language like UTF-8:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Comment: Is your HTML set with the meta tag for correct encoding?
<meta charset="UTF-8">

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to change the unicode to UTF-8 encoding . I think you are using some other type of encoding .

```
          <?php

          ini_set("default_charset", "utf-8");

          ?>
```

If you are saving Portuguese word with your script, Select UTF-8 encoding while you save the document.